# I'm trying to use Html attributes on a Html.Textbox Html helper method to dispay overided CSS formating

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I following this tutorial

http://benkaminski.com/2014/08/30/how-to-customize-bootstrap-3-popovers-individually-using-only-css/

I'm trying to deploy an over ride to Bootstrap CSS for popovers and use the following in my custom CSS file.

```
/* ========== BEGIN POPOVER 3 ========== */
.popover3 {
position: fixed !important;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1060;
display: none;
width: 250px !important;
padding: 1px;
text-align: left;
white-space: normal;
background-color: #bfd8ea !important;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
border-radius: 0px !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.popover3.right {
margin-right: -10px;
}
.popover3 > .arrow,
.popover3 > .arrow:after {
position: absolute;
display: block;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-color: transparent;
border-style: solid;
}
.popover3 > .arrow {
border-width: 11px;
}
.popover3 > .arrow:after {
content: "";
border-width: 10px;
}
.popover3.left > .arrow {
top: 50%;
right: -11px;
margin-top: -11px;
border-right-width: 0;
border-left-color: #999;
border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
.popover3.left > .arrow:after {
right: 1px;
bottom: -10px;
content: " ";
border-right-width: 0;
border-left-color: #bfd8ea !important;
}
/* ========== END POPOVER 3 ========== */

/* END CUSTOM POPOVERS */


.example-class3 {
background-color: #bfd8ea;
height: 77px;
width: 77px;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
float: right;
margin-top: 160px;
}
/* END EXAMPLE CLASSES */
```

I'm using Html helpers in the view to trigger the new format on a mouse over like this.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address2, htmlAttributes: new
           {
               data_container= "body",
               data_toogle = "tooltip",
               data_trigger = "focus",
               data_placement = "right",
               title = "Address2 is not mandatory"

           })
```

The example is using the following to trigger the .example3 code in the custom.css

```
      <div class="text-center example-class3" data-container="body" data-template='<div class="popover3" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>' data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Address2 is not a mandatory field"></div>
```

How do I incorporate the above line into the Razor in the Html helper textbox above to make it work using the Html helper instead of pure HTML. I could also use the pure HTML but I'm not sure how to trigger it that way from the helper method. Any advice would be awesome I've been trying for awhile now.  Thank you very very much !!!!!!!

Comment: You want a div or an input element ?

Comment: I want to trigger the popover or tooltip on mouse over focus. But I want to do it from inside on the HTML.TextBoxFor HTML helper when the person mouses over. All this is working now but I can't over ride that default puke yellow with pale black text look and the diminutive size of the thing.